# cellForItemAtIndexPath , sizeForItemAtIndexPath , insetForSectionAtIndex not getting invoked iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a `collectionView` to show images after fetching from `Coredatabase`. However , none on the methods are being called except `numberOfItemsInSection` & `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`. The delegates and data source are set properly.

Also the identifier of cell is photoCell and class is `JLTPhotoCell`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            _thumbNails = [[NSArray alloc]init]; // its declared ,don't worry about this
            _thumbNails = [[LADataModelController getSingleton] getAllSignatures];

            UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
            [layout setItemSize:( CGSizeMake(50,50))];
            [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
            self.collectionView.delegate = self;
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
            [_collectionView registerClass:[JLTPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
            [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
            self.collectionView.allowsSelection = true;
    }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"count %i" , _thumbNails.count);
    return _thumbNails.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_thumbNails.count > 0)
    {
        JLTPhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSData *thumbnailData = ((LASignature*)[_thumbNails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).signatureImage;
        UIImage* thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnailData];
        [cell setThumbnail:thumbnailImage];
        NSLog(@"image:%@",thumbnailImage);

        if (!_buttonSelect.hidden)
        {
            [cell performSelected:FALSE];
        }

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark UICollectionViewDelegate Methods

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _lastSelectedSign = [_thumbNails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!self.buttonSelect.hidden)
    {
        JLTPhotoCell *cell = (JLTPhotoCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selected = FALSE;

    }
    else
    {
        [_selectedImages addObject:[_thumbNails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        JLTPhotoCell *cell = (JLTPhotoCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell performSelected:TRUE];
      //  _buttonDelete.enabled = _selectedImages.count > 0;
    }

}

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_selectedImages removeObject:[_thumbNails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    JLTPhotoCell *cell = (JLTPhotoCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell performSelected:FALSE];
    _buttonDelete.enabled = _selectedImages.count > 0;

}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return  CGSizeMake(50,50) ;
}

-(UIEdgeInsets) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing=1;
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing =2;
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

jltPhotoCell Class
-(void) setThumbnail:(UIImage *) thumbnail
{
    [self setThumbnail:thumbnail andWithSize:(CGSizeMake(50,50))];
}

-(void) setThumbnail:(UIImage *) thumbnail andWithSize:(CGSize) size
{
    UIImageView *thumbImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnail];
    thumbImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height);
    thumbImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:thumbImageView];
}

-(void) performSelected:(bool)selected
{
    if (selected)
    {
        UIImageView *deleteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete"]];
        deleteImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - 35, 3, 32, 32);
        deleteImageView.tag = 123;
        [self.contentView addSubview:deleteImageView];
    }
    else
    {
        UIView *v = [self.contentView viewWithTag:123];
        v.hidden = YES;
        [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:v];
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What does this log show, NSLog(@"count %i" , _thumbNails.count) ?

Comment: log shows count 1 , the no. of image fetched.

Comment: Have you checked the NSLog(@"%@", _collectionView);

Comment: logging of _collectionView gives <UICollectionView: 0xc927000; frame = (8 29; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa54b550>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa54aee0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0xa5666c0>

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",_collectionView.delegate); check out this

Comment: `sizeOfItemAtIndexPath` & `insetForSectionAtIndex` are `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` methods which it doesn't look like `layout` is declaring `self` as its delegate so it won't call those methods on self in this case. Also, the check of `if (_thumbNail.count > 0)` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` isn't necessary as that method will only get called if a cell exists as long as the datasource of the CollectionViewController is set properly.

Answer (score 4):

As @highlycaffeinated I ran into this problem to. However calling invalidateLayout didn't work for me.

However assigning the delegate AFTER the datasource worked.

I changed:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

with:

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Great answer, that's a pity that Apple didn't think up about it, or even mention it in the documentation...

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was "don't forget to connect the delegate," which is the idiots version of this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I was able to solve it by calling the layout's `invalidateLayout` after assigning the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people who will encounter similar problems with UICollectionViews especially when doing it programmatically. So i had the same issue, finally found out that i had zero elements in the array that was supposed to be populated in the collectionView. So after reading the documentation it says that Collection Views will not show unless there is at least one element to be shown from the array otherwise it will give you the black screen all the way. Another issue that can happen in this scenario is the sizeForItemAtIndexPath will be called before the cellForItemAtIndexPath therefor the content of the cell like labels and images will not take their own heights but the height of the cell itself. hope this answer will help people around.